# Too similar results from random generation python

Tags: python, random, cryptography

I trying to get some random results from some options in code with many attempts. The problem is, that I have very similar results. Please, see my results:

```
./run.py
Option Option 4 have 333478 counts which is 16.674
Option Option 5 have 333631 counts which is 16.682
Option Option 3 have 332898 counts which is 16.645
Option Option 2 have 333555 counts which is 16.678
Option Option 6 have 332732 counts which is 16.637
Option Option 1 have 333706 counts which is 16.685
```

Here are the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import random
import time

options = ('Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5', 'Option 6')
attempts = 2000000
step = 1000000

rng = random.SystemRandom()

counts = {}
for option in options:
  counts.update({option:0})

start = time.time()
for i in range(0, attempts):
  index = options[rng.randint(0, (len(options)-1))]
  count = counts[index]
  counts.update({index:count+1})
  if (i % step == 0 and i > 0):
    percent = float(round(i / attempts * 100, 3))
    elapsed = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time() - start))
    print ('Step %d from %d which is %02d percent until %s' %(i, attempts, percent, elapsed ))

for key,value in counts.items():
  percent = float(round(value / attempts * 100, 3))
  print ('Option %s have %s counts which is %s' %(key, value, percent ) )

sys.exit(0)
```

It's possible to have more different results? If you will throw by dice, I'm absolutly sure that options will be much different that 16% to one of all. Thanks for any ideas

FriskyFox

Comment: What distribution of numbers do you want?

Comment: You have 6 options, randomly chosen over 2000000 iterations, and you are surprised each on got chosen 16% of the time?

Comment: I think that real random means almost 20% for one option, 13% for another, etc... So, but the

Comment: It's random. Each option has an equal chance of being chosen. How is this wrong? And in reality, if you rolled a die 2,000,000 times, it would be similar.

Comment: the standard deviation is `sqrt(n)`, so for a bucket of size 333k you'd expect a deviation of 577.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour since you'd expect, if each outcome is weighted equally, that they will occur 1/6th of the time (approx 16.667%).

If you roll a die 10 times you'd find that some numbers would by chance occur more often than others, as you point out in your answer. However, if you continue to roll then these fluctuations would balance out (if the dice is 'fair') and so each would occur 1/6*(number of rolls).

If you try increasing the number of `attempts` by another order of magnitude you'll see the fractions move closer to 1/6

Comment: You have right, too many iterations is the problem. If I've tried just 20 attemps, I got this result: `Option Option 5 have 3 counts which is 15.0
Option Option 6 have 4 counts which is 20.0
Option Option 2 have 3 counts which is 15.0
Option Option 3 have 3 counts which is 15.0
Option Option 1 have 3 counts which is 15.0
Option Option 4 have 4 counts which is 20.0
`. Maybe some 'unfair' manget will be soltuion. Thanks again to all

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, I finally found soltution. "Magnet" which is another random number and incrase chance to skip some steps

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import random
import time

options = ('Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4', 'Option 5', 'Option 6')
attempts = 20000000
step = attempts/100000
i = 0
rng = random.SystemRandom()

counts = {}
for option in options:
  counts.update({option:0})

start = time.time()

while i < attempts:
  index = options[rng.randint(0, (len(options)-1))]
  count = counts[index]
  magnet = rng.randint(0, int(attempts / step))
  counts.update({index:count+magnet})
  if (i % step == 0 and i > 0):
    percent = float(round(i / attempts * 100, 3))
    elapsed = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time() - start))
    print ('Step %d from %d which is %02d percent until %s' %(i, attempts, percent, elapsed ))
  i+=magnet

total = sum(counts.values())
for key,value in counts.items():
  percent = float(round(value / total * 100, 3))
  print ('Option %s have %s counts which is %s' %(key, value, percent ) )

sys.exit(0)
```

Now I have this results:

```
Option Option 3 have 2867927 counts which is 14.313
Option Option 5 have 3190916 counts which is 15.925
Option Option 2 have 3593919 counts which is 17.936
Option Option 4 have 3479163 counts which is 17.364
Option Option 6 have 2886322 counts which is 14.405
Option Option 1 have 4018966 counts which is 20.058
```

Thanks to everyone :)